# iAd custom transition for interstitial ads

Tags: ios, uiview, iad, interstitial

I would like to treat `ADInterstitialAd`s as a regular UIView's to gain some flexibility in their usage.

For example, the default interstitial transition is `slide up from the bottom of the screen`. I don't like that. Is it possible to modify the alpha value to be 0 at first and than change it to 1?

Another example is having different UIView in front of the fullscreen add for a small amount of time, namely just during transition process of the `ADInterstitialAd`? `ADInterstitialAd`s tend to be the topmost view in view hierarchies. I imagine I could do this if I manage to treat `ADInterstitialAd`s as a regular UIView. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Just an kind reminder, iAD will be closed by Apple in June 2016..

Comment: Well thank you! Was not aware of that. And the replacement will be provided by Apple?

Comment: No replacement here.. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just animate the alpha value of your `AdBannerView` to achieve the effect you want:

```
import iAd

private var bannerView: AdBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create your banner view however you want, and add it to your UI.
    bannerView = AdBannerView()
    bannerView.alpha = 0
    addSubview(bannerView)
}

// When you want to show the ad, animate the alpha.
private func animateInAd(appearing: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) [weak self] {
        self?.bannerView.alpha = appearing ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

Here is another way you can present bannerView. You can remove the view on top of the ad when it has finished sliding up:

```
import iAd

private var coverView: UIView!
private var bannerView: AdBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create your banner view however you want, and add it to your UI.
    bannerView = AdBannerView()   
    addSubview(bannerView)

    // Create the cover view however you want, and add it above the banner view.
    coverView = UIView()
    addSubview(coverView)
}

private func animateInAd(appearing: Bool) {
    let hideAdPosition = view.frame.size.height        
    let showAdPosition = hideAdPosition - bannerView.frame.size.height

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: [weak self] {
        self?.bannerView.frame.origin.y = appearing ? showAdPosition : hideAdPosition
    }) { [weak self] success in
        self?.animateCover(appearing: !appearing)
    }
}

private func animateCover(appearing: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) [weak self] {
        self?.coverView.alpha = appearing ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

EDIT:

As for `ADInterstitialAd`s, those seem to inherit from `NSObject` and have explicit methods you need to call in order to present them (`presentInView:` and `presentFromViewController:`). Therefore, there is no public API to control how these ads are presented (This is likely done on purpose so that Apple can guarantee that the ad is shown to the user).

Comment: oh nice. what about interstitial?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the second scenario? Do you mean to have a second view on top of the banner view? And then apply an alpha transition to it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include code for what I believe you are asking in the second part of your question.

Comment: thank you! these are pretty good ways of animation banner ads. they will definitively come handy. The question was actually about interstitial ads- the full screen ads. This is the link do developer library https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/. These ads tend to always slide up form the bottom of the screen and fill the entire screen space.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I'll take a look at that later today.

Comment: Answer updated. Unfortunately it looks like there are not customization points for presenting `ADInterstitialAd`s.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with this but looking at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/ADInterstitialAd_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ADInterstitialAd/) you should be able to create your own view, use `presentInView:`, and perform whatever animation you want on that view.